# How to replace hidden letter hang man

Tags: python

I am trying to make it where if you have word "man" for example it will look like this _ _ _. If the user types in "m" it will look like m _ _. I know my issue lays in the "# Where user will type guess" comment under the for loop
import random

```
user_input = ""
turns = 5

# List of words
print("Welcome to Advanced Hang Man!")
guesses = ["hello"]

# Picks a random word from the list and prints the length of it
random_guesses = (random.choice(guesses))
right_guess = []
wrong_guess = []

# Prints the hidden word in "_" format
hidden_word = "_" * len(random_guesses)
print(hidden_word)

# Where user will type guess
while True:
    user_input = input("Please enter a letter once at a time:")
    user_input = user_input.lower()
    for i in range(len(random_guesses)):
        if user_input == random_guesses[i]:
            print(hidden_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over actual word and check for the character in the `right_guesses` list. If not found, replace the character with `_` in new word. Below is the sample code to achieve this:

```
>>> my_word = "StackOverflow"
>>> right_guesses = ['s', 'o', 'c']
>>> ' '.join([word if word.lower() in right_guesses else '_'  for word in my_word])
'S _ _ c _ O _ _ _ _ _ o _'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at making the game. I'm not using your `right_guesses` list nor am i using the `wrong-guesses` but it has the basic funtionality of a hang man game:

```
user_input = ""

print("Welcome to Advanced Hang Man!")

random_word= 'bicycle'

hidden_word = "_" * len(random_word)

going = True

while going:
    print(hidden_word)
    user_input = input("Please enter a letter once at a time:");
    user_input = user_input.lower()
    for i in range(len(random_word)): 
      if user_input == random_word[i]:
        print ('Letter found!')
        temp = list(hidden_word)
        temp[i] = user_input
        hidden_word = ''.join(temp)
        if (hidden_word == random_word):
          print ('You Won!!! The word was ' + random_word)
          going = False
```